# Best and cheapest way to store around 30TB of Data

Tags: pc, data-storage

I am looking for the best and cheapest way to store around 30TB of data.
Its mostly files with the size of 150MB per file which I have to read alot, so a cloud solution doesnt really fit my needs since its too slow to download a file every 15 seconds and than delete it again. Loading of such a file to my pc shouldnt really take much longer than 1 second.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the drives storing the data allowed to fail, or is the data critical?
5 8 TB drives in RAID5 would give your 32TB with a one-drive fault tolerance.

Comment: They can fail, that doesnt matter too much for me.

Comment: 4x 8 TB or 2x 16 TB then in RAID0, that'll also give you very fast read and write speeds. Maybe you can get a good deal on some ex-Chia HDDs.

Comment: I need to buy a suitable NAS for this aswell or how would I set it up the best way ?

Comment: Depends on your PC. My case would fit up to four 3.5" drives, so 2 x 16 TB would be trivial.

Comment: Do you actually need RAID? Is a single drive fast enough for the workload on its own? I wouldn't use RAID0 unless you're trying to get more performance. 150 MB/s read speed is possible with a single high end HDD on its own. You can still use other solutions to make a single "drive" span multiple physical drives without RAID0. (Windows Spaces, JBOD, LVM, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for the **best** and **cheapest** way to store around 30TB of data.

best and cheapest almost never coincide.

**cheapest:**

- lowest cost storage, as in TB per dollar, is 3.5" hard disk drives, either in 4,6,8,10,12 TB size each.
- It is over a few years ago, that I priced X tb disks per cost, to determine TB/$, to know which size disk was the best size for the buck.  You would need to do that now given current economy and whatever prices are.  Then get *N* disks of that size to meet your needs.
- Ideally get all the same make & model because you will be **RAID-0**'ing them together to reach your 30TB or whatever size.  This RAID-0 combining is the cheapest way.
- Additionally you will need a pc motherboard with enough SATA ports and a tower large enough to hold N 3.5 hard disks to meet your ~30TB size.  If you got 10TB disks, figure 4 of them to account for formatting which results in around 90% of usable disk of what's advertised on the label.
- Choose a pc motherboard that offers INTEL RAID capability, which many do now, and can be had under $100
- Know that consumer motherboard hardware raid built into the motherboard is sketchy and a lot of people have complained about it over the years.  I tried using it years ago, was problematic, never bothered with it since.  Cheap != Best but it can work, and there's other ways to volume together N disk it does not have to be at the hardware raid level.  You can also just Have *N* disks show up separately as D: E: F: and so on and split your data manually, unless you really require **one** volume of 30TB under one drive letter or folder name.

**Best:**

- buy the same setup of *N* ? TB disks
- make sure the disks are on the synology approved list so they work as intended and are reliable, don't buy the cheapest brand you find on amazon or ebay.
- get a Synology NAS, such as a DS1515 5-bay unit, for around $500 not including hard drives
- configure as needed, such as RAID-5 to be disk fault tolerant.
- will be the most reliable in long run for not losing data
- I only use synology as an example here because I have first hand experience with them, there are other makes, look up NAS as in network attached storage.

and come to think of it **online cloud storage** might actually be the *cheapest* these days, you would have to price it out for cost over time versus somewhat of a one-time setup cost to have your storage local and physically in your presence and control, and what *best* is for you.  Obviously if you don't have [fast | good] internet connection then you kinda don't have access to your ~30tb of data.

Answer (score 0):

Two hard drives in RAID 0 is cheap and fits in most PC cases. You don't need a NAS if you have 2 SATA ports free